# Modifying the source document for linked tables in Google Slides

Tags: google-sheets, google-slides

I have Google Slides presentations I use as report templates with data in charts and tables linked to a Google Sheets document. In some cases I need to change the document that is the source for the data in the presentation while keeping the format the same (e.g. a new version of the spreadsheet).

Google Slides allows you to change the range for the data in the table, but not the document itself.

The only way I've seen so far to modify the source document for linked objects is with a script like the one proposed in this [post](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/17125948/duplicate-google-slides-with-linked-object-chart-update-or-change-the-google-sheet-source?hl=en&msgid=32357025).

The problem is that only works for linked charts, but not for tables. I'm trying to do the same for linked tables, but the issue I've ran into is that instead of working through ids like charts, tables work by defining a range in the linked sheet.

Does anyone have a solution to change the Sheets source for linked tables?

Comment: Hi. You said _update the source for linked objects_. Would you please edit your question to explain EXACTLY what you understand by this. I ask because `UPDATE` (within Slides) is a specific, well-documented, procedure.

Comment: Edited to clarify. It's changing the document that holds the data from one spreadsheet to another one, not updating the data in the table from the same source.

Comment: I am facing the exact same problem. Did you find a solution for this one?

Comment: Unfortunately not, still manually updating tables. Some day I'll dive into google apps script documentation to see if there is a way. Hope to report with good news.